# Multiple seq scans on the same filters

Tags: postgresql-9.3, sql-execution-plan

I wanted to ask why by execution of a simple query optimizer decide to execute seq scan twice using the same filter appending the results at the end?

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM customers c
WHERE ((name IS NOT NULL) AND (flag = 4) AND (birth_date < now()));
```

PostgreSQL version 9.3.4
Output of EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
Aggregate  (cost=4444780.90..4444780.91 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=50654.137..50654.137 rows=1 loops=1)

  ->  Append  (cost=0.00..4444776.28 rows=1847 width=0) (actual time=50654.128..50654.128 rows=0 loops=1)

        ->  Seq Scan on customers c  (cost=0.00..4439681.76 rows=1845 width=0) (actual time=50614.774..50614.774 rows=0 loops=1)

              Filter: ((name IS NOT NULL) AND (flag = 4) AND (birth_date < now()))

        ->  Seq Scan on customers c  (cost=0.00..5094.52 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=39.349..39.349 rows=0 loops=1)

              Filter: ((name IS NOT NULL) AND (flag = 4) AND (birth_date < now()))

Total runtime: 50654.245 ms
```

Comment: Your explain output does not match your statement (e.g. there is no aggregate in your statement, yet there is a call to an aggregate in the explain output). Please show us the full/real statement you are running

Comment: yes, sorry it was just not * but count(*)

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained runnable example demonstrating this? It looks ... odd.

Comment: hmmm I know it's odd :) It's example from production db, but I can try simulate the same situation in sqlfiddle. Maybe it's a matter of table size? It's quite huge...

Comment: I wasn't unfortunately able to reproduce this execution plan on any of other environment. Maybe there is some setting or statistical parameter I can provide to help resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Borys, I would say you better write to the postgresl mailinglist: pgsql-general@postgresql.org
Your problem sounds quite exotic (since it only happens to you).
It is a friendly bunch over there: they will help since postgres9.3 is supported.

(Sorry, this was meant to be a comment, NOT the answer.)